# How to find main() function in a big project

Tags: java

I never used Java, but I'm looking over a big server project writting in Java with Eclipse.
My question is, how can I find the main() function, is there an easy way, or I have to search for it in every .java file ?

Comment: before the funny comments on the topic ;)

Comment: grep? "Find in Files"? Every sane development environment (yes, that includes both IDEs and the shell of your choice) should support that. Also: most big projects don't have a single entry point (and many don't even have a `main`: web applications, webservices, ...).

Comment: @ bestsss: i like funny people

Comment: You can't use something like "find in files"?  Eclipse should have something like that, and if not, many other programs do...

Comment: if you're on windows, navigate to project folder and write `main` to search box, it'll appear, if not open terminal, go to project folder and execute command `grep -Iir main . *`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will have to do a code base wide search as it could be in any file. Having said that, many server based project do not have a main() function at all. The server provides the infrastructure and only looks for classes which inherit from specific other classes or implement certain interfaces or are mentioned in certain config files. All of this depends on the server and the technologies employed.

You need to find out what your server is, what technologies have been used in the java project and how it was setup.

Comment: I need to find out what command line arguments I need to pass to the server :)

Comment: @vBx unfortunately it's still going to come down to the server technologies employed. You need to find out what the server is - TOmcat, WEbSphere, JBoss, GlassFish, etc, etc. Then you will need to delve into their doco and ask more precise questions as to how to make the changes you need.

Comment: One other thing regarding the discussions below about main methods - Don't be surprised if you find main methods and later work out that they are not being used. I've often found that some programmers add main methods to server programs so that they can test them from a command line. I don't recommend this because I believe it's wrong to pollute production code like this, but others think it's fine.

Answer (score 9):

1. Use eclipse's build in search function and search for "`main(`" in all projects java files (= entire workspace)
2. Look for *the* application jar and look at it's manifest file, it may contain the name of the main class
3. Look for scripts that are used to start the application. You eventually find the `java` call that starts the application (a parameter is the main class)
4. Look for build scripts (`build.xml`). Eventually they contain some jar, install or deploy target where startup scripts are autogenerated or manifest files are written. The main class should be named there.

BTW - If the *big server project* is a server based application, say the final build result is a *war* or an *ear* file, then the entry point doesn't have to be a static `main` method. Then it might not even have *one* single starting point.

Comment: Thanks - the xml files were the key for me and an unrestricted eclipse-wide search found them.  The project I am tinkering with defines `<attribute name="Main-Class" value="net.dowobeha.wristsaver.HourGlass" />` in build.xml.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if nothing else, you could use the Search menu, Java, and use "main(String[])" as the search string. Search for: Method, Limit To: Declarations and Search In: Sources. That will help your search.

If you have a run configuration in Eclipse, you can look in that and see which class and method is being invoked.

Answer (score 2):

In your project you may have more than one `main()` method. So, you should search it in files. Just find main which is declared as `public static void`.

If you use an ECLIPSE you can try to search with special ECLIPSE search features (menu Search -> Java...).

Answer (score 1):

You better know where it is, because with Java, you can have several `main()` for one project.

I sometimes have one that runs the project as an application (standalone) and another that runs it as an applet.

The best practice is: know where it is, put it in an obvious place (like in the `Main.java` file).

Answer (score 1):

Under eclipse Package Explorer right click on project name -> Run As -> Java Application
Eclipse will automatically search and execute main method i.e. `public static void main(String[] args) {...}`